# batch - unpack files in time interval

Tags: batch-file, intervals

I have a script that unpack .rar files in its own folders. Now I want that the script unpack the .rar files, if this failed it should tries to unpack again. After 5 retries this failed, it should move the folder with his unpacked files to a new location folder I called Error.

So far I have this:

`:CopyDirectories
for /D %%D in ("%BaseSourceFolder%\*") do (
set "TargetFolder=%BaseSourceFolder%\%%~nxD"
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" x -cfg- -y "%%~fD\*.*" "!TargetFolder!"
if not errorlevel 1 (
del "%%~fD\*.r??"
move "%%~fD\*.*" "!TargetFolder!">nul 2>nul
move "!TargetFolder!" "E:\New">nul 2>nul

) else (
for /l "!TargetFolder!" in (1, 1, 5) do (
goto CopyDirectories
move "!TargetFolder!" "E:\Error">nul 2>nul
    )
  )
)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move everything into the 1...5 loop and break out of it in case of success using `goto` or `exit`:

```
for /L %%z in (1,1,5) do (
    echo try #%%z

    ............. do something

    if not errorlevel 1 goto done
)
:done
```

Comment: Had forgot to set the `goto CopyDirectories` above. What you are suggesting is exactly as in the example above or not ?

Comment: No. Replace "do something" with your copying commands and that's all.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot break out of a FOR /L command like that. It will still execute all iterations regardless of your goto.